# Split a page horizontally with page breaks

Tags: page-breaking, minipage, mdframed

I am looking for an adequate package to split horizontally all pages of an article into two parts with page breaks.

The expected behaviour shall be as in following picture:

[image]

I already try with the minipage package but it does not allow the page breaks. I also look for the mdframed package but I can not find an easy to understand working example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in, showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}


\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}[t][0.5\textheight][t]{\textwidth}
        \begin{multicols}{3}
            \lipsum[4-10]
        \end{multicols}
    \end{minipage} \\
    \begin{minipage}[b][0.5\textheight][t]{\textwidth}
            \lipsum[15-25]
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It can't be guaranteed that the floats of the first page will remain on the bottom of the first page, etc.

Comment: The [flowfram](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/flowfram) pack­age en­ables you to cre­ate frames in a doc­u­ment such that the con­tents of the doc­u­ment en­vi­ron­ment flow from one frame to the next in the or­der in which they were de­fined.